# What's the informal word for a small challenge?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english, contemporary-english

Example:

I challenge you to get her number. If you get it, you earn a beer.

It's sort of a friendly bet. It's a short 3-5 letter word. I've heard it but can't recall it. Please help.

Something pertaining to: bet, challenge, dare, play, sport, game, toy.

May also relate: a clever move, trick, stunt, tactic.

Comment: Consider this situation as a sort of challenge. Then the word would be?

Comment: Example: "I challenge you to get her number." Some kind of bet.

Comment: Is the answer "dare"?

Comment: The answer is not "dare". It may mean a small, little dare.

Comment: You might be thinking of the informal contraction *betcha*, i.e. "(I) bet you", as in "Betcha can't get her number."

Comment: Tell me you're not thinking of [**tip**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tip) are you? See def. No.3 and 4. Please, tell me it's not *tip*.

Comment: @mari, no it's not "tip". It's not so common a word. And it's really irritating me now that i try to recall it everyday and can't. I guess I'll have to use meditation to try and recall this god forsaken word. I thank you for your efforts though. :)

Answer (score 21):

A word I've heard used in this context is a *wager*, which [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wager) defines as:

> An agreement under which each bettor pledges a certain amount to the other depending on the outcome of an unsettled matter.

In this case, the unsettled matter is whether the lady will give the challenged party her number. The challenger is pledging a free beer to the challenged party; if the challenged party accepts, they are pledging to get her number.

Given the casual nature of the bet, this might even qualify as a *friendly wager*, a phrase whose popularity is shown in this [nGram plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friendly+wager&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriendly%20wager%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Its popularity pales when compared to [*"a bet"* and *"a dare"*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friendly+wager%2Ca+dare%2Ca+bet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfriendly%20wager%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20dare%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bet%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I bet you are right :)

Comment: Only in one movie - Trading Places :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was a little worried about that wording. What I meant to say was the graph showed the phrase *friendly wager* is in use rather than it being a popular term.

Answer (score 16):

[**Dare**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dare) seems to be the right word to use in this case. It may not be the actual word you are looking for but it certainly fits very well:

> to tell (someone) to do something especially as a way of showing courage

Source: Merriam-Webster

> I dare you to go to her and get her number. If you succeed, I'll buy you a drink!

I have only one reservation that *dare* plus a reward is not inherent in what I feel is the original meaning, however *wager* seems so old fashioned, and I would likely use ***dare*** myself if I wanted to ***challenge*** a friend to go on a dare even if I would add the extra reward to the successful completion.

If you google for *dare you her number* you get

> - First, Chris dared me to ask the girl in line at the movies for her number.
> - One night his friends dare him to ask for the dark skater girls number
> - "Try to get her number....... We Dare You." (Nike ad)

The word ***bet*** already suggested is a better word if your friend will have to buy YOU a beer if he does not succeed

Comment: In my view, dares are rarely associated with a reward (other than the respect of peers or the avoidance of punishment). I'm not sure it's a great fit when beer is on the line.

Comment: I sort of agree. See my update

Comment: The OP mentions *dare* and *bet* in his question. Why not add *challenge* too in your post, while you're at it?

Comment: It is there....

Comment: Ooh you cheeky thing!

Answer (score 6):

I [defy](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/defy) you to get her number.

Per [Meriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defy):

> *defy*: to challenge to do something considered impossible

Comment: Except it is not considered impossible... I would also expect HER to be the defiant one: _She looked at him mockingly, defying him to try to get her number_

Answer (score 3):

A **deal**

> *noun* 1. An agreement entered into by two or more parties for their mutual
>   benefit, especially in a business or political context
>   [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deal)

When the Op states that it is a word related to a game or sport, perhaps he was thinking of a card game where each player is *dealt* a hand that consists of several cards.

A synonym for the word *challenge* is a ***test***.
The Free Dictionary defines it as:

> A series of questions, problems, or physical responses designed to
>   determine knowledge, intelligence, or ability.

There's also the term ***test match***

> a game or series of games of cricket or rugby played by teams from
>   different countries
>   [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/test%20match)

Connected to the expression *bet* which is often heard in the world of sports and games alike is ***stake***

> *Sports & Games*
>
> a. Money or property risked in a wager or gambling game. Often used in
>   the plural. See Synonyms at bet.
>   b. The prize awarded the winner of a contest or race.
>   c. A race offering a prize to the winner, especially
>   a horserace in which the prize consists of money contributed equally
>   by the horse owners.
>    [T.F.D](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stake)

Its plural form, ***stakes***, is commonly used in the game of poker. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker#Table_stakes_rules) says:

> All casinos and many home games play poker by what are called **table
>   stakes** rules, which state that each player starts each deal with a
>   certain stake, and plays that deal with that stake. A player may not
>   remove money from the table or add money from his or her pocket during
>   the play of a hand. In essence, table stakes rules creates a maximum
>   and a minimum buy-in amount for cash game poker as well as rules for
>   adding and removing the stake from play.

Comment: A small challenge, e.g. I challenge you to get her number.

Answer (score 3):

Storyline:

> What happened was that while at work one of my colleagues asked me to
>   get a girl's number. He promised me a beer if i succeeded in getting
>   her number. So i went to the girl and asked whether she knew any
>   swimming pool nearby the place. She said that she knows one and that
>   she will get me the details. So i asked for her number by saying that
>   I'll call her to note the details. That's how i got her number.
>   Somehow she came to about the beer agreement with my colleague. So the
>   next day she asked me whether I really wanted to know about the
>   swimming pool or was it a **_**?

The word is

### PLOY

*A cunning plan or action designed to turn a situation to one’s own advantage*
TFD defines it as: [a manoeuvre or tactic in a game, conversation, etc; stratagem; gambit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ploy)

Example: *My opponent became increasingly frustrated by my beginner's luck and masterminded a cunning ploy to level the scores*

---

### List of words related to the world of gambling and trickery

> 1. [**gambit**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gambit)
>      A device, action, or opening remark, typically one entailing a degree of risk, that is calculated to gain an advantage: e.g. *The loser of this copycat election will lament all the strategic gambits that fell short in the end*.
> 2. [**flutter**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flutter)
>      *British informal* **A small bet**: *a flutter on the horses*
> 3. [**ruse**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ruse#ruse)
>      An action intended to deceive someone; **a trick**: e.g. *Eleanor tried to think of a ruse to get Paul out of the house*
> 4. [**lure**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/lure)
>      a. Tempt (a person or animal) to do something or to go somewhere, especially by offering some form of reward:
>      b. A type of bait used in fishing or hunting:
> 5. **[wile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/wile)**
>      *verb*: **Lure**; **entice**: *Mike Upchat was not his real name, of course, and no one ever found out what this was; it was also not the only pseudonym he would employ in his schemes to wile his way into a woman's bed.*
>      *noun*: Devious or **cunning stratagems** employed in manipulating or persuading someone to do what one wants.
> 6. [**gull**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/gull#gull-2)
>      Fool or deceive (someone): *They are gulled by the oldest trick of all, the one that gets the victim to look somewhere else.*
> 7. **[punt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/punt#punt-3)**
>      a. *verb* (In some gambling card games) place a bet against the bank.
>      b. *verb*: British informal Bet or speculate on something: *investors are punting on a takeover*
>      **punt** noun *informal , chiefly British*  another term for **a bet**
>
> <sup>All definitions from Oxford Dictionaries.</sup>

Comment: This is helpful and i feel that we're very close to that word now. But unfortunately it's not in this list as well.

Comment: @PraveenSinghmar have a closer look. Don't do this to me! C'mon.

Comment: Lol. I understand that you're as impatient now as I'm. Or maybe more. But I'm trying my best to recall and will share it the moment it comes to my mind.

Comment: +1 for *gambit*. @PraveenSinghmar Do you have more information on when/where you've heard it used? Or if it sounds modern? Do you recall if the word can be used in other contexts, or if it's so slangy that you've only heard it with the one meaning? I feel like I've heard a word that starts with "juh" that matches the criteria but I can't place my finger on it (not "jinx" not "juke" not...).

Comment: @dingo_dan- what happened was that while at work one of my colleagues asked me to get a girl's number. He promised me a beer if i succeeded in getting her number. So i went to the girl and asked whether she knew any swimming pool nearby the place. She said that she knows one and that she will get me the details. So i asked for her number by saying that I'll call her to note the details. That's how i got her number. Somehow she came to about the beer agreement with my colleague. So the next day she asked me whether I really wanted to know about the swimming pool or was it a _____? <---the word.

Comment: I guess it starts with "stah" or "steh" and ends with "ch" or "tch", but again I'm not sure at all.

Comment: Sorry Mari, it's not stratagem. :-/

Comment: @PraveenSinghmar Not a sham, perhaps?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not exactly counting my chickens with that.

Comment: @Frank chickens can come home and roost for I care, and scramble with their eggs while I proclaim loudly and clearly PLOY! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It might be scam.

Comment: @Frank 'tis not. (It had better not be). I have to fly the coop now. It is Saturday after all. Ciao

Comment: Neither scam nor ploy. Scam seems to be more appropriate though. But that word, that God damned word is not scam. :-|

Answer (score 1):

If they have already been betting, you can "**raise**" someone. It technically means to increase the amount you are gambling, but depending on context can refer to proposing a harder challenge.

In this sense it's similar to a **dare** with a defined reward (normally the reward for a completed dare is only admiration/kudos/glory). Context is important, as you must already have a bet or wager established before you can raise it.

- http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/raise
- http://www.thefreedictionary.com/raise

Answer (score 1):

A task.

From Merriam Webster

> *task*: a piece of work that has been given to someone : a job for someone to do